# How do i create multiple Virtual machines under the same cloud service in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to created many virtual machines under a cloud service.

But i am not able to create more than two !! It gives an error telling deployment slot already taken.Even if i change the deployment name , it is giving the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VMs need exclusive access to the deployment so you'll only be able to create one VM at a time.

Wait until the second VM you are creating completes, then try again.